# Ruby on Rails - Test Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a test :

```
test "should not allow access" do
    get :new
    assert_redirected_to new_user_session_url
 end
```

I use devise for authentication.

I have two views for each of my actions: one normal, and one for mobile devices, so before i've used usual default view (sign_in.html.erb) -  test was pass, but when i've added a  mobile view (sign_in.mobile.erb) i've got next fail message.

**Expected response to be a redirect to http://test.host/users/sign_in but was a redirect to http://test.host/users/sign_in.mobile**

So from client testing point of view - the logic working fine, e.g. in case if user not authenticated he will be redirected to session new path (new_user_session_url). This is works for mobile devices too (mobile client will be redirected to mobile view of sign in page), but test is fail for some reasons if client is mobile device and my controller redirect to mobile view.

My question is how to fix test ? I've tried :

```
assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path

assert_redirected_to :controller => "devise/session", :action => "new"
```

but with no success and the same fail message in case if client is mobile device and redirect happens to mobile view.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking.  If you could provide clearer formatting and more information, I might be able to help.

Comment: sorry for my English, i've added some more details, hopefully it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path(:format => 'mobile')
```